# Finding the first char in a string using pointers

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that takes two arguments to a function. It should find the first char that I'm looking for and then change the letter to an x. The result in this example would be "txst". My question is why doesn't this work? The ouput of this is: xest  Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* contains(const char* string, char c){

    for(; *string; string++){
        if(strchr(string, c)){
            return string;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {

    char test[] = "test";
    char* result = contains(test, 'e');

    if(result != NULL){
        *result = 'x';
        printf("%s\n", test);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is anyone able to help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what output do you get?

Comment: Your `contains()` basically boils down to: `return strchr(string, c);`, then it should work as you expect (although `contains` isn't really the right name for it, however... Thinking further, it should be called `strchr()`... but this already exists... so maybe, you should kick the definition and use strchr ;)) I'm confused...)

Comment: I improved my question, the output is "xest".

Comment: Your code works as expected - what do you think it should be outputting?

Comment: @ChrisTurner as _you_ expect, but not as _he_ expects, when `txst` should be the outcome

Comment: @ctx ah - the question has updated to include the expected output whilst I was writing my comment

Comment: @ChrisTurner See: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17866365 <- someone corrected the output "txst" to "test" and some robo reviewers accepted that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably intended to do this:

```
char* contains(const char* string, char c) {

  for (; *string; string++) {
    if (*string == c) {
      return string;
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Actually this boils more or less down to:

```
char* contains(const char* string, char c) {
    return strchr(string, c);
}
```

Your `contains` function does the same thing as `strchr`.

Comment: *His* `contains()` function doesn't do the same thing as `strchr()`, it always returns the starting of `string`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I tried to do that before but i forgot the *, thanks a lot!

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi sure, but I wasn't refering to _his_ `contains()_ but to the one in my answer.